# How to write polars custom apply function that does the processing row by row?

Tags: python, apply, python-polars

I need to create a new column in my dataframe that stores the processed values. So I used polars apply function to do some processing of dicoms and then return value. But this apply function by default takes the entire column as polars Series and it doesn't process row by row.

```
df = df.with_columns(
        [
            pl.apply(
                exprs=["Filename", "Dicom_Tag", "Dicom_Tag_Corrected", "Name"],
                f=apply_corrections_polars,
            ).alias("dicom_tag_value_corrected"),
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 13):

As the documentation of `pl.apply` states, it should not be used in the `select` context. It should only be used in `groupby` operations to apply over different groups.

For custom functions over items, you can utilize the `Struct` data type.

Since `polars>=0.13.16` you can apply over `Struct` dtypes. A `Struct` can be composed of any column in polars.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"ham": [2, 2, 3], 
              "spam": [11, 22, 33], 
              "foo": [3, 2, 1]})

def my_complicated_function(struct: dict) -> int:
    """
    A function that can not utilize polars expressions.
    This should be avoided.
    """

    # do work
    return struct["ham"] + struct["spam"] + struct["foo"]

df.select([
    pl.struct(["ham", "spam", "foo"]).apply(my_complicated_function)
])
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ ham │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 16  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 26  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 37  │
└─────┘
```

Comment: Wow.  This new approach using struct performs *much* better!  I benchmarked this approach using the struct expression versus the solution using map and a list of expressions.  I created a dataframe of 4 columns of 10 million integers each, and a trivial row-wise sum function (lol - not that one should *ever* use either approach for calculating row-sums).  The old approach took 49 seconds.  The new approach (using struct) used only 12 seconds!  Accordingly, I'm removing my answer.  Great job!

Comment: Nice! I am also thinking of removing the dataframe apply in favor of this. That should make it clear that there is a single way of doing this.

Comment: NotFoundError: ham in the newest version

Comment: I think you should open an issue at github. In any case, I can confirm that this snippet runs successfully on latest release on pypi.