# Polars str.starts_with() with values from another column

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars DataFrame for example:

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B': ['app', 'nop', 'cap', 'tab']})
>>> df
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ app │
│ b   ┆ nop │
│ c   ┆ cap │
│ d   ┆ tab │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I'm trying to get a third column `C` which is `True` if strings in column `B` starts with the strings in column `A` of the same row, otherwise, `False`. So in the case above, I'd expect:

```py
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ app ┆ true  │
│ b   ┆ nop ┆ false │
│ c   ┆ cap ┆ true  │
│ d   ┆ tab ┆ false │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

I'm aware of the `df['B'].str.starts_with()` function but passing in a column yielded:

```py
>>> df['B'].str.starts_with(pl.col('A'))
...  # Some stuff here.
TypeError: argument 'sub': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
```

What's the way to do this? In pandas, you would do:

```py
df.apply(lambda d: d['B'].startswith(d['A']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I am just starting to learn polars and there may be other ways, but I think we can compare them in their own slices. `df.with_column(
    (pl.col('B').str.slice(0,1) == pl.col('A').str.slice(0,1)).alias('bool_')
)`

Comment: @r-beginners This is a good start, what I want to do is a little more complicated, hence why I want to use the `starts_with` function since column A could be longer strings

Comment: It looks like only a couple of the regex methods in the `.str` namespace [are currently set up to accept expressions.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/polars/internals/expr/string.py#L580) Perhaps this should be filed as a [feature request.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature was [added](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6355) in [polars 0.15.17](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.15.17)

```
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col("B").str.starts_with(pl.col("A")).alias("C"))
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ A   | B   | C     │
│ --- | --- | ---   │
│ str | str | bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   | app | true  │
├─────┼─────┼───────┤
│ b   | nop | false │
├─────┼─────┼───────┤
│ c   | cap | true  │
├─────┼─────┼───────┤
│ d   | tab | false │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after toying around for a bit, this works but I'm pretty sure uses Python strings in the back (based on the function name `startswith`) and therefore is not optimized:

```py
>>> pl.concat((df, df.apply(lambda d: d[1].startswith(d[0]))))
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ apply │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ app ┆ true  │
│ b   ┆ nop ┆ false │
│ c   ┆ cap ┆ true  │
│ d   ┆ tab ┆ false │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

I'll put up a feature request on Polars to see if this can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct) is another option if polars>=0.13.16. This approach, however, also uses [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75154585/18059879), instead of [`polars.Expr.str.starts_with`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.starts_with.html#polars.Expr.str.starts_with).

### Code:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B': ['app', 'nop', 'cap', 'tab']})

df.with_column(
    pl.struct(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda r: r['B'].startswith(r['A'])).alias('C')
)
```

### Output:

```
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ app ┆ true  │
│ b   ┆ nop ┆ false │
│ c   ┆ cap ┆ true  │
│ d   ┆ tab ┆ false │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

### Reference:

[How to write polars custom apply function that does the processing row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71679606/18059879)