# pandas explode() alternative for polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

In pandas when I am using `df.apply(someFun,axis=1)` which goes to a function in which a list of zipped values i.e. `list(zip(val1,val2))` is being returned.
And then `df.explode()` is used.

But in `polars` when using
`df.with_columns((pl.Series(list(someFun(x)) for x in df.iter_rows(named=True)).alias(column1)))`.

It is creating a hexadecimal values in `Column1`.

using pandas:

```
self.var1 = 'A'
self.var2 = 'B'

def someFun(row):
    var  = self.var1
    var2 = self.var2
    cal1 = row[var] + row[var2]
    cal2 = row[var] * row[var2]
    return list(zip(cal1 , cal2))

df["column1"] = df.apply(someFun,axis=1)
exploded_df = df.explode("column1",ignore_index=True)
```

in polars dataframe value in column1 is like **b"\x00O\**, and explode is throwing error on this column.

tried converting the hexadecimal value to list but can't update it back in the dataframe so that explode function can work.

Comment: Can give a runnable code example that creates hexadecimal values? i.e. the real `someFun`

Comment: your `someFun` is using numbered indices not named ones so why are you using `iter_rows(named=True)`

Comment: yes I have done it for the example, initially it is using named indexing. I have updated the example.

Comment: We still cannot run your example unfortunately, there are no `self` or `df` definitions. The example function doesn't really help either as it doesn't produce the `b''` strings you mention. You'll have to give us code that allows us to run your `df.with_columns()` line to produce the same error.

Comment: I've voting to close. This question is eerily similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788887/polars-apply-function-dosent-pass-column-name-to-function). Seems like a bot or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polars apply function dosen't pass column name to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788887/polars-apply-function-dosent-pass-column-name-to-function)

Comment: @michael_s no i noticed that both the values cal1 and cal2 are of different data types like int and str. casted both in str and than apply zip(), and it worked for me